# chmod and chown have no effect on mounted CIFS share, but emit no error either

Tags: mount, fstab, chmod, chown, cifs

I have an SMB share on a Buffalo NAS (nas01/storage) mounted on /storage. From /etc/fstab:

```
//nas01/storage /storage cifs file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0750,uid=1000,gid=1000,passwd="XYZ" 0 0
```

It mounts fine and I've set **file_mode** and **dir_mode** to prevent the "all 777" bit that happens by default (apparently) so that's all OK. Files and directories are created 644 adn 750 as desired, as my account (UID 1000). I can create, edit, rename and delete files/dirs but cannot chmod/chown them (as my account nor root).

```
$ ls -l testfile2
-rw-r--r-- 1 len len 0 Nov 28 21:11 testfile2
$ chmod 755 testfile2 
$ ls -l testfile2 
-rw-r--r-- 1 len len 0 Nov 28 21:11 testfile2
```

No errors, it just doesn't work.

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS now, but previously had CentOS 6.8 installed, accessing the same share. I don't *seem to recall* running into this on CentOS, but I can't say that for sure. I may well have simply have not encountered or noticed it since I didn't run CentOS here for very long.

Am I mounting the SMB share improperly or is there fundamentally something preventing it? What do I need to change?

Thanks!